# Error when I want to generate app bundle with Android Studio : need to update Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I’m trying to publish my app in the Android App Bundle format.
I tried to do it with Android Studio. I opened my project (the folder platforms/android) and then I made Build Bundles/APK -> Build Bundles
When I do that, Android Studio says to me:

```
Building Android App Bundles requires you to update to the latest version of the Android Gradle Plugin. Learn More
App bundles allow you to support multiple device configurations from a single build artifact. App stores that support the bundle format use it to build and sign your APKs for you, and serve those APKs to users as needed.
```

Yet I am up to date,

```
Android Gradle Plugin Version - 4.0.1
Gradle Version - 6.5.1
```

and when I do Update, Shows-

> Failed to update the version of the Android Gradle Plugin.
> Please click 'OK' to perform a textual search and then update the build files manually.

I've attached the reference screenshots of the error I am facing.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9nG3.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hMCq.png)

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLFRl.png)

[Image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsHj5.png)

I am not able to generate my Android App Bundle.

Comment: change gradle version to 6.1.1

Comment: Yes ! I Changed the Gradle Version, but the problem is same. Trying to build bundle apk but it shows 'Building Android App Bundles requires you to update to the latest version of the Android Gradle Plugin'